Send Automatic Follow Up Emails a certain number of days after a Dropdown Selection Status
I have an appscript code for custom emails that send to a specified person when I select a status dropdown for an item on the spreadsheet. When I select "Request Sent" it fires off an email to the owner of the item with the details from the spreadsheet using the template I typed.
I would like to be able to add in addition to the trigger-based status emails, automatic reminder/follow up emails which would go out, for example, 7 days after the initial "Request Sent" status is selected on the spreadsheet if the status hasn't been changed for that item yet. And/or an email that would go out automatically, for example, 3 days before the due date I entered on the spreadsheet (Column H).
Here is my current code:
function checkMySheet(e) {
  let range = e.range;
  let source = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  let row = range.getRow();
  let col = range.getColumn();
  let val = range.getValue();

  if (source.getName() == "Individual Licenses" && col == 6 && val == 'Request Sent') {
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = ss.getSheetByName(source.getName());
    let data = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 12).getValues().flat();
   
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: data[4],
        subject: `ACTION REQUIRED: License Item Needed for ${data[0]}`,
        htmlBody: `
       Hey ${data[3]},<br />
       <br />
       Please see the below details for an individual license item that requires your attention so we can clear this with the regulator. It is important that you please review this as soon as possible and let me know if you have any questions on what may be needed to address and clear the item.<br />
      <br />
       <strong>STATE</strong>: ${data[0]}<br />
       <strong>LICENSE ITEM</strong>: ${data[1]}<br />
       <strong>PRIORITY</strong>: ${data[2]}<br />
       <strong>ASSIGNED TO</strong>: ${data[3]}<br />
       <strong>DUE DATE</strong>: ${Utilities.formatDate(new Date(data[7]), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"M/d/yy")}<br />
       <strong>NOTES</strong>: ${data[11]}<br />
       <br />
       If you need any help or additional clarification then please don't hesitate to reach out and let me know. Also please keep me updated on the status and your expected time to have this completed.<br />
       <br />
       Thanks!<br />
       <br />
       `
      })

  ss.toast("Email successfully sent!", "STATUS", 5);
  }

Mark down example:



State
License Item
Priority
Owner
Email Addresses
Status
Date Requested
Due Date
Date Completed
Milestone
Documents
Notes




California
Continuing Education Required (2024)
Medium
Kerry
example@gmail.com
Request Sent
11/9/2024
12/6/2024

Active






Kindly share a minimal, reproducible example—no sensitive data with your desired output—that the community can use to replicate and see what you'd like to do.

You may use Tables to create one, with tools like Table to Markdown to help you easily copy and paste the data from the spreadsheet into the question, and as a last resort (not recommended since access may be revoked after the question has been answered), you can also Make an anonymous sample document.

How is your function executed

@Cooper the snippet of code pasted above is executed by a trigger of when a SmartChips Dropdown selection is selected as "Request Sent" on the applicable sheet

I'm assuming that your reply to @Cooper's comment means that the script runs using an installable trigger. As for the script you provided, it doesn't state what's on Column G, Column I, Column J, and Column K, which is why I wanted to see what's in the spreadsheet.

@Saddles edited with the markdown sample. Thank you for your help.

I've read the existing scenario and script - sounds good. But then "I would like to be able to add": what I do not understand is "What is the problem?" The scenario describes a script triggered by a (daily?) time-driven trigger that responds to the "Status" and/or "Due Date".  Have you tried to write code for this, have you researched for other scripts that do this? It is an interesting scenario but not too complicated, and the existing script suggests a competent developer. Again, "what is the problem?", because  StackOverflow is not a bespoke code-writing service.

Related question: Google Script: Send email 7 days before date in cell.

I don't think on selection change fires the way you think it does and you should also check out the event object my guess is that it's a lot different than the onEdit event object.  I think it fires on any selection changes like changing sheets and changing ranges etc. I'm not really sure what the problem is because I don't use that trigger much

I think you just need a daily trigger and store the date that the drop down is changed using an onEdit trigger then when the daily trigger finds the date that's 3 days old it sends the email.  Don't use onSelectionChange at all.

The goal is to either send a follow-up email 7 days after the initial "Request Sent" status is set in Column F and is still not changed, send an email 3 days before the due date set in Column H, or both.
Both options are possible; however, for the first one, I suggest using Column M as a timestamp for the Request Sent in Column F, which would be a week from that date. I think this is also @Cooper's point in his last comment.
You may add the following to the checkMySheet(e) function after the email has been sent to achieve that:
sheet.getRange(row, 13).setValue(new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7)));

The full code would become:
function checkMySheet(e) {
  let range = e.range;
  let source = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  let row = range.getRow();
  let col = range.getColumn();
  let val = range.getValue();

  if (source.getName() == "Individual Licenses" && col == 6 && val == 'Request Sent') {
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = ss.getSheetByName(source.getName());
    let data = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 12).getValues().flat();

    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: data[4],
      subject: `ACTION REQUIRED: License Item Needed for ${data[0]}`,
      htmlBody: `
       Hey ${data[3]},<br />
       <br />
       Please see the below details for an individual license item that requires your attention so we can clear this with the regulator. It is important that you please review this as soon as possible and let me know if you have any questions on what may be needed to address and clear the item.<br />
      <br />
       <strong>STATE</strong>: ${data[0]}<br />
       <strong>LICENSE ITEM</strong>: ${data[1]}<br />
       <strong>PRIORITY</strong>: ${data[2]}<br />
       <strong>ASSIGNED TO</strong>: ${data[3]}<br />
       <strong>DUE DATE</strong>: ${Utilities.formatDate(new Date(data[7]), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "M/d/yy")}<br />
       <strong>NOTES</strong>: ${data[11]}<br />
       <br />
       If you need any help or additional clarification then please don't hesitate to reach out and let me know. Also please keep me updated on the status and your expected time to have this completed.<br />
       <br />
       Thanks!<br />
       <br />
       `
    });
    sheet.getRange(row, 13).setValue(new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7)));

    ss.toast("Email successfully sent!", "STATUS", 5);
  }
}

Note: Assuming that you're using an Installable Triggers for onEdit() to run the script, what it should do now is that every time Request Sent is set in Column F, an email will be sent to the user in Column E, and a date will show up in Column M, which would be today's date + 7 days.
To send the emails, here's a sample code that you may use with a daily Time-driven triggers:
function myFunction() {
  // Variable names from the other function
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Individual Licenses");
  let data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 13).getValues();
  // Newly declared variable names
  let today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  data.forEach(r => {
    let colH = new Date(r[7]);
    let colH3D = new Date(colH);
    colH3D.setDate(colH.getDate() - 3);
    colH3D.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    let colM = new Date(r[12]);
    colM.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    if (today.getTime() == colH3D.getTime()) {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: r[4],
        subject: `${r[0]} is due in 3 days`,
        htmlBody: `Kindly finish ${r[0]} immediately!`
      });
    }
    if (today.getTime() == colM.getTime()) {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: r[4],
        subject: `${r[0]} — 7 days in Request Sent`,
        htmlBody: `Kindly update ${r[0]} immediately!`
      });
    }
  });
}

I've opted to create another function so that its sole purpose is to check what you'd like and send emails based on it.
OUTPUT


UPDATE
To make the script work only for Individual Licenses, Branch Licenses, and Company Licenses, it can be modified to:
function myFunction() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  ["Individual Licenses", "Branch Licenses", "Company Licenses"].forEach(sheet => {
    let sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheet);
    let data = sh.getRange(2, 1, 1, 13).getValues();
    data.forEach(r => {
      let colH = new Date(r[7]);
      let colH3D = new Date(colH);
      colH3D.setDate(colH.getDate() - 3);
      colH3D.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
      let colM = new Date(r[12]);
      colM.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
      if (today.getTime() == colH3D.getTime()) {
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: r[4],
          subject: `${r[0]} is due in 3 days`,
          htmlBody: `Kindly finish ${r[0]} immediately!`
        });
      }
      if (today.getTime() == colM.getTime()) {
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: r[4],
          subject: `${r[0]} — 7 days in Request Sent`,
          htmlBody: `Kindly update ${r[0]} immediately!`
        });
      }
    });
  });
}

Note: Don't forget to create a time-driven trigger in Google Apps Script to allow the code to run automatically, so that you won't have to manually execute it in the editor.

Thank you so much! This is perfect.
Quick question though, if I wanted to use this function for multiple sheets (with each sheet having the email template customized for that sheet). How would I do that?

I have three sheets total. They all have the same columns and same datasets. One is for "Individual" one for "Branch" and one for "Company". So this added reminder emails and due date emails for the "Individual sheet" but I also want to set up for the other two sheets.

If you want it to work on all of the spreadsheets, you can change let sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Individual Licenses"); to ss.getSheets().forEach(sheet => { and move the closing }); at the end of the script.

I remember that your previous question has a total of six spreadsheets, with three of them hidden. Kindly keep in mind that by doing that in the code, when the trigger runs, it'll also check the hidden sheets to check if any of them would return true.

If you'd like the script to only work on the sheet names you've provided, I'll go ahead and update my answer with that information when you respond.

Can you confirm this was able to address your question, @KamronKimbrough?

sorry for the delay in responding, I would like the script to only work on the following sheets: "Individual Licenses", "Branch Licenses", and "Company Licenses"

This is my current code I tried because I need the script to be only those three sheets and I need the reminder emails to be separate templates for each type of reminder and for each sheet... however this code currently isn't working. I never created a trigger for the 'myFunction' function so maybe I need to do that?

That's alright! I'll go ahead and update my answer to only work with Individual Licenses, Branch Licenses, and Company Licenses when I get home. As for I never created a trigger for the 'myFunction' function so maybe I need to do that? Yes, you'll need to create a time-driven trigger that would run on your specified hour of day.

I've updated my answer to only work on the sheet names you provided. I believe creating separate templates for each type of reminder and for each sheet would be a separate question, so I recommend that you post a new one if you're having issues modifying the script, as your original request was to send emails 7 days after the initial "Request Sent" status is set in Column F as well as 3 days before the due date set in Column H.
